# Como plotar esse sinal no MatLab?

Tags: matlab

Queria plotar esses sinais no MatLab para fazer uma série de fourier, mas não estou conseguindo. Alguém sabe está o erro? Além disso, como eu incluo a unidade imaginário? Eu coloquei como 1j mas não sei se está certo

```
clear all;
close all;

T=1;
w0=2*pi/T;
c=4;
T1=T/c;
t=linspace(0,2*T,1000);

N=5;
a=zeros(N);

a(0)=2/c;

for i=1:N-1
    a(i)=(2/c)*sin(w0*i*T1)/(w0*i*T1);
end

a_neg=zeros(N);
a_neg(0)=0; 

for i=1:N-1
    a_neg(i)=(2/c)*sin(-w0*(i)*T1)/(-w0*(i)*T1);
end

x_aprox_0=a(0)+a_neg(0);
x_aprox_1=a(0)+a_neg(0)+a(1)*exp(1j*w0*t)+a_neg(1)*exp(-1j*w0*t);
x_aprox_2=a(0)+a_neg(0)+a(1)*exp(1j*w0*t)+a_neg(1)*exp(-1j*w0*t)+a(2)*exp(2*1j*w0*t)+a_neg(2)*exp(-2*1j*w0*t);
x_aprox_3=a(0)+a_neg(0)+a(1)*exp(1j*w0*t)+a_neg(1)*exp(-1j*w0*t)+a(2)*exp(2*1j*w0*t)+a_neg(2)*exp(-2*1j*w0*t)+a(3)*exp(3*1j*w0*t)+a_neg(3)*exp(-3*1j*w0*t);
x_aprox_4=a(0)+a_neg(0)+a(1)*exp(1j*w0*t)+a_neg(1)*exp(-1j*w0*t)+a(2)*exp(2*1j*w0*t)+a_neg(2)*exp(-2*1j*w0*t)+a(3)*exp(3*1j*w0*t)+a_neg(3)*exp(-3*1j*w0*t)+a(4)*exp(4*1j*w0*t)+a_neg(4)*exp(-4*1j*w0*t);

figure;
plot(t,x_aprox_0);
plot(t,x_aprox_1);
plot(t,x_aprox_2);
plot(t,x_aprox_3);
plot(t,x_aprox_4);
hold on;
grid on;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu script tem vários erros, mas eles são todos facilmente resolvidos.

Vou colocar inicialmente umas dicas de como resolver os problemas quando se está programando!

---

- **Preste atencão ao retorno do Matlab**

Quando você roda algo e falha, o *interpreter* lhe retorna um erro.

No seu caso:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Diferente de [python](/questions/tagged/python) que comeca em 0, [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) comeca a contar em 1!

Daqui pra frente, assumo que todos os erros relacionados com isso foram corrigidos!

---

- **Verifique como uma funcão funciona antes de utilizar**

Você pode utilizar `help nome_da_funcão` na linha de comando pra ver o que ela precisa de entrada e o que ela retorna como saída.

Você usa

```
a=zeros(N); %isso é uma matrix 5x5
```

Porém, você quer usar

```
a=zeros(N,1); % ou  a=zeros(1,N);
```

Que lhe dá uma coluna (ou linha). Isto é o que você está usando como coeficientes.

- **Cuidado ao mexer com coisas imaginárias**

  plot(column,imag_number_column)

terá o resultado

```
 plot(column,real(imag_number_column))
```

---

Coisas menores que é bom saber:

> ```
> clear all
> ```

Em geral, use apenas `clear`, pois o Matlab guarda parte do código na memória pra optimizar o tempo pra interpretar&rodar.

> `figure`, `plot` e `hold`.

Quando utilizar vários gráficos na mesma figura, utilize isso na sequencias:

```
figure
plot 
hold
plot
```

ou

```
figure
hold
plot
plot
```

ou até mesmo sem declarar a `figure`. Matlab irá criar uma figura caso não exista nenhuma quando hold ou plot for chamado. E a execucão do gráfico é imediata (diferente de, por exemplo, [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) que precisa de `draw` para desenhar o gráfico). Quando um plot não está em `hold`, ele irá apagar o que já estiver plotado.

> ```
> plot(t,x_aprox_0);
> ```

Olhe que o que você quer plotar é a mesma coisa que você declarou. Neste caso, `x_aprox_0` é apenas um ponto. Não creio que seja o resultado que você quer, mas foi o que você declarou em

```
x_aprox_0=a(1)+a_neg(1) ;
```

onde os dois valores são constantes (veja que já corrigi o índice).

> ```
> x_aprox_1=a(1)+a_neg(1)+a(2)*exp(1j*w0*t)+a_neg(2)*exp(-1j*w0*t);
> ```

Veja que os valores fazem sentido. Neste caso, `a_neg(2)` e `a(2)` são próximos a zero.

---

Vamos ao resto do seu código. Você não deixou claro o que o código faz, e você pode editar a sua pergunta e comentar na minha resposta para nos entendermos melhor.

Pelo que entendi você que ter o sinal em frequências diferentes pra fazer uma transformada de Fourier. Nisso você está falhando, mas como não tenho certeza se é isso que você quer, vou escrever minha ideas. Se for o caso, coloco o código depois, editando a minha resposta:

1. Você quer 4 frequências mais o seno original.
2. Cada sinal será adicionado ao sinal anterior.
3. O plot irá conter os 5 sinais, sendo o original mais as somas.

Se isto for a caso, existem algumas maneiras de escrever a resposta. O seu não está longe disso, mas as frequências não estão certas. Porém caso você queira modular a intensidade, o seu resultado está mais próximo. Porém você tem valores muito próximos a zero.